# Can't seem to get my executable bin to run

Tags: java, xml, macos, terminal, izpack

On my mac, I am trying to create a installer using izpack. Whenever I run the installer (after i compile of course) in terminal, it runs fine, and prompts for the user to install the latest java runtime at the end of the install. If i simply click the runnable installer.jar, the installer never attempts to run the bin file. What am i missing??

here is a copy of my install xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
```

```
<!-- 
    The info section.
    The meaning of the tags should be natural ...
-->
<info>
    <appname>Beldon Workbench</appname>
    <appversion>0.1 Beta</appversion>
    <authors>
        <author name="JPz" email="jpz@superman.org"/>
        <author name="Hidden Man" email="hidden@hisdomain.com"/>
    </authors>
    <url>http://www.anotherworld-inspace-website.net/</url>
</info>

<!-- 
    The gui preferences indication.
    Sets the installer window to 640x480. It will not be able to change the size.
-->
<guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>

<!-- 
    The locale section.
    Asks here to include the English and French langpacks.
-->
<locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    <langpack iso3="fra"/>
</locale>

<conditions>
        <!-- checks that the correct JRE version is installed on the windows machine -->
    <condition type="java" id="jre.version">
        <java>
            <class>CheckVersion.Check</class>
            <field>isCorrectVersion</field>
        </java>
        <returnvalue type="boolean">true</returnvalue>
    </condition>
        <!-- condtion checks for windows needing updated jre -->
    <condition type="and" id="jre.windows.install">
        <condition type="ref" refid="jre.version"/>
        <condition type="ref" refid="izpack.windowsinstall" />
    </condition>
        <!-- condition checks for mac needing updated jre -->
    <condition type="and" id="jre.mac.install">
        <condition type="ref" refid="jre.version" />
        <condition type="ref" refid="izpack.macinstall" />
    </condition>
</conditions>
<!-- 
    The resources section.
    The ids must be these ones if you want to use the LicencePanel and/or the InfoPanel.

<resources>
    <res id="LicencePanel.licence" src="Licence.txt"/>
    <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="Readme.txt"/>
</resources>
-->
<!-- 
    The panels section.
    We indicate here which panels we want to use. The order will be respected.
-->
<panels>
    <panel classname="HelloPanel"/>
    <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
    <panel classname="PacksPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
</panels>

<!-- 
    The packs section.
    We specify here our packs.
-->
<packs>

        <!-- Core Java files- i.e. class files -->
    <pack name="Core" required="yes" override="asktrue">
        <description>Core Application Files</description>
        <fileset dir="../../../Users/homemac/Documents/Beldon/WorkbenchTest/core" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/core"/>
            <!-- installs jre8 if needed on windows machine -->
        <executable targetfile="jre8.exe" stage="postinstall" failure="warn" condition="jre.windows.install" />
            <!-- installs jre8 if needed on a mac machine -->
        <executable type="bin" targetfile="/Applications/IzPack/bin/script/installjreMac.bin" stage="postinstall" failure="warn" condition="jre.mac.install" keep="true" />
    </pack>

        <!-- Database folder for comparison tables (updates) -->
    <pack name="DB" required="yes">
        <description>Database Files</description>
        <fileset dir="../../../Users/homemac/Documents/Beldon/WorkbenchTest/db" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/db"/>
    </pack>
        <!-- 3rd Party Libraries -->
    <pack name="libs" required="yes">
        <description>3rd party libraries</description>
        <fileset dir="../../../Users/homemac/Documents/Beldon/WorkbenchTest/libs" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/libs"/>
    </pack>
        <!-- Cache folder for holding update files -->
    <pack name="cache" required="yes">
        <description>Temporary Update Files</description>
        <fileset dir="../../../Users/homemac/Documents/Beldon/WorkbenchTest/cache" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/cache"/>
    </pack>
        <!-- Log files folder -->
    <pack name="logs" required="yes">
        <description>Log Files</description>
        <fileset dir="../../../Users/homemac/Documents/Beldon/WorkbenchTest/logs" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/logs"/>
    </pack> 
</packs>

<jar src="../lib/CheckVersion.jar"/>
```

and here is a copy of my java class to check for the latest version

```
public class Check {

public static boolean isCorrectVersion = checkVersion();

public static boolean checkVersion() {
    boolean property = false;
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
    String ver = p.getProperty("java.version");
    System.out.println(ver);
    Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("^([1-2]{1}\\.\\d+){1}.*$");
    Matcher m = ptn.matcher(ver);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    //double v = 1.8;
    if(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)) < 1.8) {
        property = true;
    }
    return property;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you already have the JRE installed, and thus the "after installed JRE" hook is never executed on your local machine.

Try using a virtual machine (virtualbox is super handy, and only takes a few minutes to boot a new ubuntu desktop instance) to test your installs on a fresh system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. Currently I am running 1.7 on my machine. I can run DTRACE from terminal and inside the installer there is a window displaying all my variables and checks. The check for the JRE   returns true so i know it is working. My main problem is I do not know what could cause my bin file to run when run from terminal and what would keep it from working when .jar is launched through finder. Thanks again I will try virtual box to see if that clears anything up.